# ssh connect to self server connection refused

Tags: ssh

I have a server and on it, I am developing a shell script that involves ssh connecting to itself (as to share the same server in dev phase), the problem is that no matter what account I use, `ssh user@ip.address` always result in "ssh: connect to host ip.address port 22: connection refused".

I have asked my ISP and port 22 is not restricted at all. And I am sure ssh/sshd are installed correctly on the server.

What could be the possible cause?

Comment: Are you sure that the port is open, can you connect using localhost?

Comment: I can connect using localhost. And I am sure the port is open because I can connect to it from my desktop. It's just connecting to it from itself is problematic.